# Generalizing numeral systems for natural numbers

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in unique representations of natural numbers in the following sense:

Let $B$ be a fixed ordered set

$$ B = \{ b_k : \,  b_{k+1} > b_k > 0 \} $$

with positive natural numbers $b_k$.

For any finite natural number $n$ there should exist a set

$$A(n) = \{ a_k \ge 0 \} $$

with natural numbers $a_k$, such that the representation

$$ n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k b_k $$

is unique, i.e. that for any two sets

$$ A(m) \neq A(n) \implies m \neq n $$

holds. Examples are numeral systems with

$$ B = \{ b_k = b^k \} $$

$$ 0 \le a_k < b $$

My question is if there are other reasonable sets $B$ for which uniqueness holds.

Comment: You're always going to need $\ b_0=1\ $, but you can cetainly generalise $\ b_k\ $ to a product $\ c_1c_2\dots c_k\ $, where each $\ c_i\ $ is merely restricted to being $2$ or more, rather than having $\ c_i=b\ $ for all $\ i \ $. For unique existence of the representation you'll need $\ a_k\ $ to satisfy $\ 0\le a_k<c_{k+1}\ $ for all $\ k\ $.

Comment: Thanks, sounds reasonable. I'll look for some proof. That still seems to exclude a lot of options for $B$; does it exhaust all possibilities, or are there more?

Comment: If your $\ a_k\ $ are restricted to be consecutive  non-negative  integers starting from zero, I think these will be the only possibilities, but I haven't seen a proof of that.

Comment: The first question is if the $b_k$ have to be products of integers. Suppose $n_K^+ = \sum_{k=0}^K a_k^+ b_k$ is the largest number that can be constructed for some $K$. Then the smallest number for $K+1$ should be $n_{K+1}^- = n_K^+ + 1 = 1 \cdot b_{K+1}$. I do not see how the restriction for the $b_k$ to be products would follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof of the conjecture I made in one of the comments above, namely, that if the values that can be taken by $\ a_k\ $ are $\ 0,1,\dots,$$ c_{k+1}-1\ $, then $\ b_k=\prod_\limits{j=1}^kc_j\ $.

The largest natural number that can be represented by $\ k\ $ "digits" in the representation is
\begin{align}
&c_1-1\hspace{3em}\text{if }\ \ k=1\ \text{, or}\\
&c_1-1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\big(c_{i+1}-1\big)b_i\hspace{3em}\text{if }\ \ k>1\ ,
\end{align}
and the smallest that can be represented by $\ k+1\ $ "digits" is
$$
0\cdot b_0+0\cdot b_1+\dots+1\cdot b_k=b_k\ .
$$
If there were any natural number lying strictly between these two , it would not be representable by any sequence of "digits", so we must have
\begin{align}
b_1&=c_1=\prod_{j=1}^1c_j\hspace{3em}\text{and}\\
b_k&=c_1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\big(c_{i+1}-1\big)b_i\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\ b_i=\prod_\limits{j=1}^ic_j\ $ for $\ i=1,2,\dots,k-1\ $, then
\begin{align}
b_k&=c_1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\big(c_{i+1}-1\big)\prod_{j=1}^ic_j\\
&=c_1+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\Big(\prod_{j=1}^{i+1}c_j-\prod_{j=1}^ic_j\Big)\\
&=c_1+\prod_{j=1}^kc_j-c_1\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^kc_j\ .
\end{align}
It follows by induction that $\ b_k=\prod_\limits{j=1}^kc_j\ $ for all $\ k\ $.